# what is this strange "script" doing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing some test then find below code would pop up a window:

```
<a href="script:test">test</a>
```

looks like it is trying to open an application.
Can anyone tell me what is the usage/purpose of this "script"?
looks like FF, Chrome, and IE all support it.

Comment: It passes the argument `test` to whatever application you have mapped to launch the `script` protocol (**not** the same as JavaScript's `javascript:` protocol).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`script` is being used as a protocol. No applications handle the `script` protocol, so clicking it does nothing useful.

You can register a custom protocol handler and if the user accepts it, your application will be allowed to open all links of that type (there are [only a few permitted protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler)):

```
window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler('web+test', 'http://example.org/?handler=%s', 'Test Protocol');
```

Only `example.org` will be allowed to run the above code, but if you open your dev tools while visiting http://example.org/ and run the above code, you will get a dialog asking you to allow or deny the protocol association. If you accept it, click the following link on any website:

```
<a href="web+test:hello">test</a>
```

It will redirect to http://example.org/?handler=hello

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think this is correct and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to open an application? That script is just a hyperlink, it does not tell anything else in the script, just that it will open a link into site that tells "test"

Comment: hmm, you could try it. On FF, it indeed opens a window asking to choose an application.  if you use something like ascript, then it behaves like a hyperlink

Comment: Then it must be part of some other script, could u post the whole script? Not only that part? If it is an application can u anyhow edit it or open it in notepad to read what the code in it is saying?

Comment: You might want to explain what the protocol identifier in a url does and how you can configure it, for example by looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers